# Module declaration with same name for property and function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am writing definitions for an existing function module library which exposes the following API:

```
fn().from(opts: Options)
// and
fn().from.string(path: String)
```

I found about declaration merging [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). Where it says something about declaring many times a function with the same name for overloads. But it says nothing about writing types for a function and a property living in the same place.

Nevertheless I tried writing:

```
export interface Test {
    from(path: string): ToOptionsBuilder;
}
export interface Test {
    from: FromOptionsBuilder;
}
```

But as expected, the compiler complains: `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.`

Is there anything I can do about it ?

In case of need, the library is [markdown-pdf](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use declaration merging for a field. You can declare the field to conform to the declaration you want by using an intersection type between a function signature and the `FromOptionsBuilder` interface:

```
export interface Test {
    from: FromOptionsBuilder & {
        (path: string): ToOptionsBuilder;
    };
}

//Test
interface FromOptionsBuilder { fromField : number }
interface ToOptionsBuilder { toField: number}
declare let t: Test;
t.from.fromField
t.from("").toField
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20from%3A%20FromOptionsBuilder%20%26%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(path%3A%20string)%3A%20ToOptionsBuilder%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FTest%0D%0Ainterface%20FromOptionsBuilder%20%7B%20fromField%20%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ToOptionsBuilder%20%7B%20toField%3A%20number%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20t%3A%20Test%3B%0D%0At.from.fromField%0D%0At.from(%22%22).toField)

If you want users of the module to be able to add overloads to the `from` function, you can use an extra interface to be the interface others can merge their overloads in:

```
export interface Test {
    from: IFormFunction
}

export interface IFormFunction extends FromOptionsBuilder {
    (path: string): ToOptionsBuilder;
}
//Extended overload 
export interface IFormFunction  {
    (path: string, otherValue: string): ToOptionsBuilder;
}
//Test
interface FromOptionsBuilder { fromField : number }
interface ToOptionsBuilder { toField: number}
declare let t: Test;
t.from.fromField
t.from("").toField
t.from("", "").toField
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20from%3A%20IFormFunction%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IFormFunction%20extends%20FromOptionsBuilder%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(path%3A%20string)%3A%20ToOptionsBuilder%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F%2FExtended%20overload%20%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IFormFunction%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(path%3A%20string%2C%20otherValue%3A%20string)%3A%20ToOptionsBuilder%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F%2FTest%0D%0Ainterface%20FromOptionsBuilder%20%7B%20fromField%20%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ToOptionsBuilder%20%7B%20toField%3A%20number%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20t%3A%20Test%3B%0D%0At.from.fromField%0D%0At.from(%22%22).toField%0D%0At.from(%22%22%2C%20%22%22).toField%0D%0A)

Comment: Oh for sure ! I forgot about intersection type because it was a function, but yeah, a function is a type to. Thanks !